Why Do I Receive a Pragma Error when building in Rider?
I'm getting an error when building a project in Rider saying #pragma once in main file
The strange thing is that my friends building the same project in Rider for Windows have no problems building and debugging the solution.
Any clues as to what's going on?

#pragma once should only be used in header files (not cpp files). Maybe your friend is building with a different compiler or more relaxed warning settings (not recommended)

@PepijnKramer they are also using Rider, but on Windows. I'll have them check their settings. Thanks for the insight!

The effect, if any, of #pragma once is up to the compiler.

@JaredBarden Using a header guard in your .cpp file may generate a warning but it shouldn't result in an error unless you've turned it into an error via compiler options.

Either your project's "main file" is just a little different from the one your friends have (e.g. due to some edit not shared/applied correctly), a different version of the development environment, or the development environment is configured differently.
